# Visual Studio Less formatting, Intellisense/Errors

Tags: visual-studio-2012, less, intellisense

I am using Visual Studio 2012 and use LESS for my CSS. The problem I am having is that my page was the red squiggly line under every comment that starts with 2 forward slashes "//", which is a valid way to add comments in LESS. Visual Studio is adding these red lines all over the page when I know for certain everything on the page is valid. So it is not recognizing LESS properly. I have installed the Web Essentials extension, but this doesn't fix the issue. Is there another extension I can use, or something that I can install with Visual Studio that will do a better job validating the page?

Comment: What happens if one of those lines is commented out by being placed between /* .... */ rather than //? If you mouse over one of the lines with red squiggle underline does it tell you what it thinks the problem is? (Generally when VS marks something mousing over will give an idea what it thinks is wrong)

Comment: Have you installed the latest VS2012 update? (They are up to Update 4)? http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39305 . Using Visual Studio 2012 and Web Essentials the Intellisense does work for me when I add a `LESS stylesheet` to a VB.net C#.net or Website application. The `//` do work. I assume you are editing files with `.less` extension? If you have LESS inside a `.css` Intellisense won't understand that it is actually a LESS file. If I create a `.css` file and put `//` in it, VS will complain with red squiggly and "Expected a selector for the style rule." as the reason.

Comment: Effectively if your filename doesn't end in `.less` Intellisense will not understand it as less file. You can't have a `.css` file and expect Intellisense to understand that it should be processing it as a LESS file. So the big question is what is the file extension of the files you are editing? My guess is they are `.css` (but just a hunch)

Comment: I just installed the latest update for VS2012 and I am still seeing the red lines. Yes this is within a file with the .less extension. When I put them between /* ... */, it is fine, but that is a standard CSS comment, I'm trying to make it work for LESS which should support the //. When I hover over the red line it says "Unexpected token { expected"